# Json value NSDictionary conversion

Tags: javascript, ios, json, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with my app.

```
 render()
 {
  console.log( this.state.ext);
  var tmp = this.state.ext;
  tmp = tmp.toString();
  console.log(tmp);

  if (this.state.ext != ""){

return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={require('../../img/mob.png')} style= {styles.mob_logo}/>
    <WebView
    source={{uri: {tmp}}}  style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
  </View>
)
}
```

i get JSON value

```
{
    tmp = "React Native New Date string"";
}
```

of type NSDictionary cannot be converted to NSString.

Answer (score 0):

you can use yourDictionary["tmp"] or yourDIctionary.Description to convert it into string

Comment: i don't know to do that can you explain me ?

Comment: When you get a dictionary, you get the string or object out of it using a key or you can log the description of your dictionary to see its structure